# How do I delete an Array of an Array in mongoDb

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

This is my document structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5841eba5d3693034c49da7d7"),
"Key" : "01041655",
"matchingKey" : "01041655",
"brand" : "Brand",
"name" : "Product Name",
"availabilities" : [ 
    {
        "data1" : [ 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "4.5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }, 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }, 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "5.5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "data2" : [ 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "4.5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }, 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Im not sure if it's the best way to do it like that, so please let me know if there is a better way to do that. My question is: How can I delete the array data1 or data2. And what is the best way to do that in Java. My current Java code looks like that:

```
Document array = new Document("availabilities", dataKey);
Document updateSet = new Document("$unset", array);
prodCollection.updateMany(eq("matchingKey", matchingKey), updateSet);
```

But this code deletes all documents in availabilities.

**UPDATE1:**
I changed the document structure like that:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5841eba5d3693034c49da7d7"),
"Key" : "01041655",
"matchingKey" : "01041655",
"brand" : "Brand",
"name" : "Product Name",
"availabilities" :  {
        "data1" : [ 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "4.5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }, 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }, 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "5.5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }
        ],         
        "data2" : [ 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "4.5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }, 
            {
                "number_a" : null,
                "number_b" : "5",
                "number_c" : null,
                "number_d" : null,
                "amount" : 0,
                "lastCheck" : "2016-12-02T22:46:13.393+01:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now i can delete in mongodb the specific arrays like that:

```
db.products.update({"matchingKey":'01041655'},{$unset: {"availabilities.data1":1}});
```

How can I do that in Java? I tried it like that:

```
Document array = new Document("availabilities.data1", 1);
Document updateSet = new Document("$unset", array);
prodCollection.updateOne(eq("matchingKey", matchingKey), updateSet);
```

But it still deletes all arrays.

Comment: what is the criteria for deleting the values inside the availability array ?

Comment: The names data1 and data2. Do i have to set them as names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an misunderstanding with the $set operator. It replaces the old data with the new one. Due to that I don't need to delete the array. I just needed to use $set like that in Java:

```
Document availDoc = new Document("availabilities."+key, availabilities);
Document updateSet = new Document("$set", availDoc);
prodCollection.updateOne(eq("matchingKey", matchingKey), updateSet);
```